# Understanding Recursion on Binary Trees

Tags: python, recursion

Hello I am new to programing so at school we are learning recursion and binary trees. But for me recursion is something that really melts my mind away.

so I was trying out a recursive function on a Binary Tree trying to output the preorder format

```
def preorder(self, preorder_list):
    """ (BinaryTree) -> list
    Return a list of the items in this tree using a *preorder* traversal.
    """

    if self.root is not EmptyValue:
        if self.left and self.right != None:
            preorder_list.append(self.left.preorder(preorder_list))
            preorder_list.append(self.right.preorder(preorder_list))

def helper_preorder(self):
    preorder_list = []
    self.preorder(preorder_list)

    return preorder_list
```

When I run this code the output I get is:

for example;

```
[None, None, None, None]
```

Now I suspect this has to be a problem with my recursive reasoning. So I would like to know what is the problem with my recursive reasoning and how I can better my self in recursion.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Because the list you are passing in is empty?

Comment: `if self.left and self.right != None:` is not correct it would be `if self.left is not None and self.right is not None:` or `if self.left  and self.right` if you wanted to include all falsey values

Comment: oh but I wanted an empty list so that I can append to it.

Comment: I don't know Python but I could post the same in Java; it 'adds' to a list. You surely don't need to be checking the left and right for anything; just call it again for both; your first check handles it next time.

Comment: humm I am still having trouble understanding this... Because I am pasing an empty list so that I can append to it.

Comment: @Ali Passing the empty list is fine, but your `preorder` function never returns a useful value to append to that list. See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're never returning anything from `preorder`, and Python is implicitly returning `None`. So you append the return value of the function to your list, but that value is `None`. Your function should look like this (In pseudo code, not valid Python)<sup>1</sup>:

```
preorder(node, list):
    if node is Empty:
        return list
    else:
        new_list.append(node.data)
        preorder(node.left, new_list);
        preorder(node.right, new_list);
        return list
```

Note that I am duplicating the return statement, so you could optimize this, but I set it up this way because it's easiest to understand recursion if you think of it as a base case or a recursive call.

To understand recursion<sup>2</sup>, think about breaking a hard problem into smaller, easier problems. I'll take a simple example, one of the classic recursion examples: `factorial(n)`.

What is `factorial(n)`? That's a really hard question to answer, so let's find something simpler.

From math class, we know that `n! = n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...*(2)*(1)`, so let's start there. We can immediately see that `n! = n * (n-1)!`. That helps; now we can write a starter of our factorial function:

```
factorial(n):
    return n * factorial(n-1)
```

But it's not done yet; if we run that, it'll go forever and not stop<sup>3</sup>. So we need what's called a base case: a stopping point for the recursion, where the problem is now so simple that we know the answer.

Fortunately, we have a natural base case: `1! = 1`, which is true by definition. So we add that to our function:

```
factorial(n):
    if n == 1: return 1
    else return n * factorial(n)
```

Just to make it clear how that works, let's do a trace for something small, say `n=4`.

So we call `factorial(4)`. Obviously `4 != 1`, so `factorial(4) = 4*factorial(3)`. Now we repeat the process, which is the beautiful thing about recursion: applying the same algorithm to smaller subsets of the original problem, and building up a solution from those parts.

Our trace looks something like this:

```
factorial(4) = 4*factorial(3)
factorial(4) = 4*3*factorial(2)
factorial(4) = 4*3*2*factorial(1)
```

Now, we know that `factorial(1)` is: it's just 1, our base case. So finally we have

```
factorial(4) = 4*3*2*1
factorial(4) = 24
```

---

<sup>1</sup> This is only one possible way; there are others, but this is what I came up with on the spot
<sup>2</sup> You must first understand recursion (Sorry; I couldn't resist)
<sup>3</sup> In the real world, it will eventually stop: because each recursive call uses some memory (To keep track of function parameters and local variables and the like), code that recurses infinitely will eventually exceed the memory allocated to it, and will crash. This is one of the most common causes of a stack overflow error

Comment: @Ali `node.data` is how you identify the node. My model is a simple one where each node only contains one thing (A positive integer, say), but in realistic implementations you would store a unique key and some other information (Like a name) in the node

Comment: okay when I try that.. it gives me an error: saying

builtins.NameError: name 'preorder' is not defined

Comment: @Ali What I posted isn't valid Python, it's pseudocode. I'm just showing you what logic you should be following, not exactly what code to write

Comment: yes. The code I have written is returning the error. Actually in my program I do not have a .data attribute or any attribute that lets me know the value of the node explicitly... Hence what I am trying to do is actually append directly to the list like this:

preorder_list.append(preorder(self.right, preorder_list))

Comment: @Ali At some point you need to return *something* from `preorder`, otherwise Python will create a list full of he default return value (Which was the point of your question). To append just the node itself, I'd change my code to `list.append(node)` rather than `node.data`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63644/discussion-between-jason-baker-and-ali).

Comment: Thanks for all the great info, help and advice. Helped me alot !